# Question about a general solution of a Differation Equation and a special case for second order

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In general for a system of IVP
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}=Ax+b(t) && x(t_0)=x_0
\end{align*}
we can write the solution as 
\begin{align*}
x(t)=\Phi(t) \Phi(t_0)x_0+\Phi(t)\int _{t_0}^t\Phi^{-1}(s)b(s)
\end{align*}
What I am trying to understand is how is the formula the same as would be obtained using the method of Variation of Parameters for a 2nd order linear non-homogeneous ODEs.

What I was thinking is to consider a general second order ODE
$$y''+P(t)y'+Q(t)y=b(t)$$
Then my thought was to write it as a system of equations to be able to batch this to the formula.

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_1\\
x'_2
\end{bmatrix}
 =&
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 &1\\
    -P(t) &-q(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
+&
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
b(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Then I am really not sure. I mean I do not need a solid proof more of what I want is to see how are the solution using variation of parameters the same as the formula we have using the fundamental matrix.